# How to stop all sites being redirected to SSL on IIS7.5

Tags: http, https, iis-7.5

I have a web server with a number of sites hosted on it. One of those sites requires SSL and the redirection is handled within the web.config of that site.

The rest of the sites do not have an SSL option.

It was recently noticed that if a user enters https://ourunsecuredomain.co.uk, they are taken to the site that requires SSL.

I've tried removing the redirect instructions from the the web.config but that hasn't helped. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move your SSL website to a dedicated IP address. This should resolve your issue. If you install SSL certificate on a website which is using shared IP address, SSL certificate will appear for all websites hosted on that IP address.

Since IIS 7/7.5 does not support SNI, you will have to move your SSL website to a dedicated IP address.